# Uploading iOS .ipa file to testflight via Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I might be late to the CI/CD party but better late than never. So far, I am able to setup Jenkins on a separate MAC which does not contain XCode. I use this MAC as a 24x7 small server for minor operations. A lot of time was wasted for archiving and then uploading that build to testflight for my iOS apps so I thought of setting up a CI/CD process.

After the Jenkins setup, I am able to generate the .ipa file for specified target (release/debug).

Now I want to upload this .ipa file to Testflight. This is what I know already:

1. **Via ALTool:** As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384568/1364053), I should use AlTool. AlTool is nothing but the Application Loader inside XCode. I don't want to install XCode on this separate MAC, so this is not what I can work with.
2. **Via shell script:** If you see the question of the answer in the above point, the user has mentioned a script. I have tried that as well and it fails.
3. **Via Shenzen:** [This](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) is deprecated. On the Github page itself, they have mentioned to use Fastlane.
4. **Via Testflight plugin:** [This](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Testflight+Plugin) is also deprecated.

So basically, what I feel is Jenkins alone itself can not distribute iOS builds to testflight, unless we use ALTool which requires XCode to be installed. Is there a workaround to do it purely via Jenkins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a better option, strongly recommend Fastlane.

You can check [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/appstore-deployment/) and [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/) is specifically for TestFlight

You need to have Fastlane on the Jenkins but it is execution is easy and fast.

Also as we discussed you can implement connection by yourself using [AppStoreConnect API](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/)

Comment: If Fastlane does not need XCode, it would also need some API to connect to appstore/tesflight. Is that API is available publicly?

Comment: yes there is API you can find the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi but still Fastlane make it much faster. I don't work for Fastlane :)

Comment: Nice find. If possible, you can mention this in the answer itself as my question was originally to find a pure Jenkins only solution without XCode.

Answer (score 3):

Fastlane Pilot action is a better option.

You need to add Environment Variables in Jenkins

1. **FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD** - This is application-specific password generated on https://appleid.apple.com. Pilot automatically fetches password for a transporter from environment variable named `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`
2. **FASTLANE_PASSWORD** This is apple developer account password

Add below command in shell script of Jenkins

fastlane pilot upload — ipa ***IPA_PATH***

[Reference link](https://medium.com/@priya_talreja/ci-cd-in-ios-using-jenkins-and-fastlane-7b0f9218de8f)